# Minimising an expression in the form of an integral

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider a quadratic  $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with unknown .What values of $a,b,c$ will minimise the integral $$ \int_0^1(f(x)-\frac{1}{1+x})^2?$$ How do I write in Mathematatica?Can Mathematica solve it exactly?Any \help \hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
Minimize[
 Integrate[(a*x^2 + b*x + c - 1/(1 + x))^2, {x, 0, 1}], {a, b, c}]
```

Comment: Add `// Simplify` and the result is cleaner.